# Sqlachemy How to query several tables filter by several independent statement?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

The case is, here is SQL like that:

```
sql = "select p.name State, c.name City, d.name District from "\
      "info p, info c, info d "\
      "where p.id= '%s' and c.id = '%s' and d.id = '%s'" %(State, City, District)
```

I'd like to use sqlachemy to replace it, it like this:

```
session.query(info.label('State').filter(info.id == State),\
        query(info.label('City')).filter(info.id == City),\
        info.label('District')).filter(info.id == District)
```

Sure, above code have syntax error, I mean I'd like to use one `query()`, but several paras like `query(table1, table2, table3...)` each para match one or more `filter()`:

```
query(t1, t2, t3).filter(t1.0, t1.1, t2, t3)
```

I don't know if it have above statement?